# ¿Cómo crear un arreglo de estructuras dinámicas en c++?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria, estructuras

Mi pregunta es:  ¿Cómo puedo crear un arreglo de estructuras dinámicas en c++? Y necesito que el apuntador `*p` dentro de la estructura sea un arreglo dinámico. No lo puedo hacer con listas enlazadas.

Estructura:

```
typedef struct{
    int *p;
}Jugador;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más detalles de lo que defines como estructura dinámica?

Comment: O sea un arreglo creado dinámicamente y que cada espacio de este sea una estructura, y que cada estructura dentro de cada posición del arreglo tenga un arreglo también dinámico

Comment: ¿Has considerado usar [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) o [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) en lugar de punteros?

Comment: No me es permitido realizarlo de esa forma, sólo con punteros.

Comment: Deberías decirle a tu profesor de programación que no enseñe C++ en 2018 como si fuese 1995.

Comment: Vale, lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: Hay proforesores que son casi secta... una vez han conseguido una silla no se levantan de ella ni para actualizar conocimientos... aunque sea por aburrimiento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, C++ **no** es C.

**C:**

```
typedef struct{
    int *p;
}Jugadores;
```

**C++:**

```
struct Jugadores
{
  int *p;
};
```

Segundo punto:

> ¿Cómo puedo crear un arreglo de estructuras dinámicas en c++?

En vista del código de tu pregunta es posible que tu profesor te llegue a explicar la magia de una función llamada `malloc`:

```
Jugadores jugador;
jugador.j = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); // Array para 10 elementos
```

Pero claro, como hemos dicho antes, C++ **no** es C. En C++ es preferible y altamente recomendable usar `new`:

```
Jugadores jugador;
jugador.j = new int[10]; // Array para 10 elementos
```

Por supuesto no hay que olvidarse de liberar la memoria una vez deje de ser necesaria:

```
delete[] jugador.j;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo hice, gracias por las aclaraciones

Answer (score 2):

#### Preguntas.

> ¿Cómo puedo crear un arreglo de estructuras dinámicas en c++?

Usa [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new):

```
auto tamanyo = 100;
Jugadores *arreglo = new Jugadores[tamanyo];
```

> El apuntador dentro de la estructura sea un arreglo dinámico.

Usa `new`:

```
struct Jugadores {
    int *p = new int[100]{};
};
```

#### ¿Cómo hacerlo bien?

La memoria dinámica en C++ debe ser liberada después de su uso, necesitarás que `Jugadores` tenga un constructor (para asignar valores específicos al arreglo interno) y un destructor (para liberar la memoria después de su uso)

```
struct Jugadores {
    Jugadores(int tamanyo) {
        p = new int[tamanyo]{};
    }
    ~Jugadores() {
        delete []p;
    }
    int *p = nullptr;
};
```

Pero el añadir un constructor hace que la clase no sea construible por defecto y hará que falle al crearse:

```
// Error! Jugador no tiene constructor por defecto
auto tamanyo = 100;
Jugadores *arreglo = new Jugadores[tamanyo];
```

Para solucionar este problema, puedes pasar la lógica de creación del arreglo interno a una función miembro, pero la construcción se deberá hacer en dos pasos:

```
struct Jugadores {
    void reserva(int tamanyo) {
        delete []p;
        p = new int[tamanyo]{};
    }
    ~Jugadores() {
        delete []p;
    }
    int *p = nullptr;
};

// Primer paso: reservar arreglo de jugadores.
auto tamanyo = 100;
Jugadores *arreglo = new Jugadores[tamanyo];

// Segundo paso: reservar arreglo interno.
for (auto jugador = jugadores, fin = jugadores + tamanyo; jugador != fin; ++jugador)
    jugador->reserva(100);
```

Dado que `Jugadores` maneja memoria, querrás evitar que sea una clase copiable, borra los operadores de copia y asignación:

```
struct Jugadores {
    void reserva(int tamanyo) {
        delete []p;
        p = new int[tamanyo]{};
    }
    ~Jugadores() {
        delete []p;
    }
    Jugadores(const Jugadores &) = delete;
    Jugadores &operator =(const Jugadores &) = delete;
    int *p = nullptr;
};
```

Pero esto último no servirá de nada teniendo el puntero `p` públicamente accesible, así que hagámonoslo privado... pero entonces necesitaremos una manera de obtener y modificar valores, deberemos añadir el operador corchetes (versión lectura/escritura y versión sólo lectura):

```
struct Jugadores {
    void reserva(int tamanyo) {
        delete []p;
        p = new int[tamanyo]{};
    }
    ~Jugadores() {
        delete []p;
    }
    int &operator[](int indice) {
        return p[indice];
    }
    const int &operator[](int indice) const {
        return p[indice];
    }
    Jugadores(const Jugadores &) = delete;
    Jugadores &operator =(const Jugadores &) = delete;
private:
    int *p = nullptr;
};
```

Pero entonces podemos tener el problema de acceder a un índice inexistente, para evitarlo deberemos guardar el tamaño del arreglo interno:

```
struct Jugadores {
    void reserva(int tamanyo) {
        delete []p;
        p = new int[this->tamanyo = tamanyo]{};
    }
    ~Jugadores() {
        delete []p;
    }
    int &operator[](int indice) {
        if (indice > tamanyo) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Indice fuera de rango");
        }
        return p[indice];
    }
    const int &operator[](int indice) const {
        if (indice > tamanyo) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Indice fuera de rango");
        }
        return p[indice];
    }
    Jugadores(const Jugadores &) = delete;
    Jugadores &operator =(const Jugadores &) = delete;
private:
    int *p = nullptr;
    int tamanyo = 0;
};
```

#### ¿Cómo hacerlo con C++ moderno?

Como ves, trabajar adecuadamente con punteros dinámicos es complicado, mi consejo es que te olvides de los punteros, y uses contenedores estándar como [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
struct Jugadores {
    std::vector<int> p{};
};

// Primer paso: reservar vector de jugadores.
auto tamanyo = 100;
std::vector<Jugadores> jugadores(tamanyo);

// Segundo paso: reservar arreglo interno.
for (auto &jugador : jugadores)
    jugador.p.resize(100);
```

Este código con `std::vector` ofrece más garantías que la versión con puntero:

- Es más segura al incluir la copia y movimiento de manera automática.
- Maneja la memoria de manera automática.
- Ofrece el operador corchetes de manera automática.
- No "*necesita*" ocultar el `std::vector`, así no se cambia tu interfaz original.
- Es menos código, por lo que es menos propenso a errores y más fácil de mantener.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

En C++ no se requiere `struct` para referirse a una estructura (en C si es necesario):

```
typedef struct{
    int *p;
}Jugadores;
```

El código anterior crea una estructura anónima a la que le da el alias `Jugadores`.

```
struct Jugadores{
    int *p;
};
```

El código anterior crea una estructura llamada `Jugadores`. Por otro lado el nombre está muy mal escogido, Jugadores es plural y tú quieres almacenar un jugador, debería ser singular.

Comment: Iba a hacer la pregunta más completa... pero con tu respuesta ya no es necesario

Comment: Gracias, empezaré a buscar más sobre c++ moderno, me fuiste de mucha ayuda.